# How can i decrease React-Native load time

Tags: reactjs, react-native

As i known, react-native take some time to load bundle file and init to device's memory.
In my case, my bundle size about 5-6MB, then on android, it take over 10s to init app.
So how can i decrease app init time ? i try to unbundling follow [this guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/next/performance.html#unbundling-inline-requires) but it does not opimize.

Comment: How did you measure the js bundle load time ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try 'unbundling' feature(which I found the most interesting in the performance section). As it states, you can load the minified JS bundle partly, thus decreasing the initial load time.